# What is the purpose of hashing the identifier in the secure remote password (SRP) protocol?

Tags: passwords, password-hashing, srp, pake

In the secure remote password protocol version 6a, the identifier for the user, `I`, is hashed along with the salt and the password on the client.

While I understand the identifier is used to locate the verifier on the server, what is the purpose of including the identifier in the client side hash?

Does it serve a cryptographic purpose?

Is SRP weakened if I always use an empty string for `I` on the client?

Comment: [This](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8626/why-is-tls-srp-verifier-based-on-user-name/9430#9430) is answered here.

Comment: @ModalNest Thanks!